# ¿Por qué no aplica una regla CSS si el selector es más específico?

Tags: css, selectores-css

En el siguiente código:

```css
section > div {
  color: blue;
}

section div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    Texto 1
    <div>
      Texto 2
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Teniendo en cuenta que el selector `section > div` es más específico que el selector `section div` (porque afecta a unos descendientes concretos de la sección –los hijos directos– y no a todos)... ¿Por qué acaba todo el texto rojo, en lugar de ser "Texto 1" en azul y "Texto 2" en rojo?

Answer (score 5):

Aunque intuitivamente el selector `section > div` es más específico que el selector `section div`, realmente no es más específico para CSS.

Esto se debe a que **los combinadores no afectan la especificidad**, [tal y como se explica en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad):

> El selector universal (`*`), los combinadores (`+`, `>`, `~`, ) y la pseudo-clase de negación (`:not()`) no tienen efecto sobre la especificidad. (Sin embargo, los selectores declarados dentro de `:not()` si lo tienen.)

Entonces, la especificidad de ambos selectores es la misma: 0-0-2. Y como la regla con `section div` aparece después en el código, es la que tomará precedencia y se aplicará a ambos `div`.

Teniendo eso en cuenta, para que "Texto 1" aparezca en azul y "Texto 2" en rojo, habría que cambiar el orden de las dos reglas en CSS:

```css
section div {
  color: red;
}

section > div {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    Texto 1
    <div>
      Texto 2
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hay más información sobre este comportamiento en esta [publicación del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8096829/3695983), o esta [cadena de 2004 del grupo de trabajo de CSS 2.1](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2004Jul/0051.html), en la que se indica que no se va a dar peso a los combinadores.

Answer (score 3):

Con el uso de [esta herramienta](https://specificity.keegan.st/) podemos observar que ambos tienen un mismo nivel de especificidad como ya se menciona.

Sin embargo para mantener el orden de declaración de reglas CSS como están al inicio podemos hacerla mas específica declarando una clase al primer `div` que esta dentro de `section` que es su hijo directo de esta forma:

```
<div class="azul">
```

Con lo cual su especificidad ahora sería de<sup>1</sup>:

- 0 Para `ids`
- 1 Para `Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes`
- 2 Para `Elements and pseudo-elements`

```html
    <style>
      section div.azul{
        color: blue;
      }
    
      section div {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <section>
      <div class="azul">
        Texto 1
        <div>
          Texto 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Para que de esta manera se aplique un color azul a todos los elementos `div` que están dentro de `section` pero que tengan una clase `azul`, así aún por la cascada al ser mas específica la regla CSS primera se aplica al elemento.

**Referencia**

- [Especificidad en CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad#Tipos_de_selectores)

Answer (score 2):

Ese "operador" `>` no hace esa regla más especifica.

El único objetivo de `>` es poder discriminar los hijos directos de los que no lo son, pero esto no quiere decir (necesariamente) hacer una regla más especifica.

Al hacer esto:

```
section > div {color: blue;}
section div {color: red;}
```

Sólo estás diciendo que los hijos directos se pongan en azúl pero no estás dando más prioridad.